# Find a closed subset $J\subset I$ such that $f(J)=I$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f:I\subset \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function on $I=[a,b]$ and $I\subset f(I)$. Show there exist a closed interval $J\subset I$ such that $f(J)=I$.

---

My first thought is used the theorem of continuous function for closed sets, so if $U$ is closed set on $\mathbb{R}$ then $f^{-1}{(U)}$ is closed set on $I$ but I think that I have to construct this closed set $J$. Do you know some idea to do this?

Comment: Observe that I is connected,Interval is connected

Comment: @yili Oh... so I can't find other closed subset on $I$ and $J=I$ in this case. Am I right?

Comment: $I = [a,b]$ find the set of point $S_a = f^{-1}(a),S_b = f^{-1}(b)$ they are both nonempty,by $I \subset f(I)$,pick one point in $S_a$ denote it $x$ then find another point $y \in f^{-1}(b)$,that cloest to $x$,connect $x,y$,then the $J$ is the desired interval connect them.

Comment: @yili Thank you so much.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @yili Excuse me, Can I consider $[x,y]$ or $[y,z]$?

Comment: Yeah,It can be $[x,y]$ or $[y,x]$ ,anyway,you can find one.

Comment: you can prove that the inverse image will also be a connected closed interval